# How to show XAML designer for XAML drawing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010 Professional I was able to open and edit with the designer view a XAML file without it being part of a solution (going from File-> Open File).

In VS 2017 or Blend 2017 I can open the file but it shows up only the XAML code view and no ToolBox and no designer if I try to do the same.

I would like to open and edit a XAML file (adding controls and stuff) without creating a WPF solution that contains it. I just use those XAML files as static background layout for some applications.

Is that possible or I have to use VS 2010?

Here what I see:

[VS 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcr84.jpg)

[VS 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgziC.jpg)

Comment: ok I'll keep using VS 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **Enable XAML Designer** check box under *Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> General*

[image]

Also, if using resharper:  Under *Resharper Options > Environment > Performance Guide > Disable XAML Designer*.

Set to **"Ignore"**

[image]